# Two left joins and a union in MySQL

Tags: sql, mysql, mysql-error-1066

**I'm trying to do a pretty complex query in** `MySQL`; complex for me, at least.

Here's an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
SELECT * FROM friends
LEFT JOIN users ON users.uid = friends.fid1
LEFT JOIN users ON users.uid = friends.fid2
WHERE (friends.fid1 = 1) AND (friends.fid2 > 1)
UNION SELECT fid2 FROM friends
WHERE (friends.fid2  = 1) AND (friends.fid1 < 1)
ORDER BY RAND()
LIMIT 6;
```

---

I'm getting back: `ERROR 1066 (42000): Not unique table/alias: 'users'`.

Where am I going wrong, and how should I *really* be performing this query?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Alias your table, like:

```
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON u1.uid = friends.fid1
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON u2.uid = friends.fid2
```

Comment: That solved one problem. Now I'm getting back `ERROR 1222 (21000): The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns`. Any thoughts?

Comment: @Josh Smith: With respect, that's a different error so ask a new question.

Comment: Respect noted and suggestion taken! Also, I should note for any other readers that I've read that aliasing should really be done as ...`users AS u1`... for better readability. I'm not sure if there's any benefit besides that, but that's a big enough benefit for me to warrant doing so.

Comment: For those interested, I posted my follow-up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655708/the-used-select-statements-have-a-different-number-of-columns-redux

Answer (score 2):

You have written left join two times with different fields of tables, it seems to When it got parse so give them alias and then join them with `friends` Table

```
LEFT JOIN users users1 ON users1.uid = friends.fid1
LEFT JOIN users users2 ON users2.uid = friends.fid2
```