# SELECT with left join and union

Tags: mysql, select, left-join, union

I have this query that return invoices made on a certain employee shift

```
SELECT
i.dateTime,i.amount,i.totalProfit,i.shiftID,
i_o.itemID,i_o.quantity,
item.name itemName,
p.full_name

from invoice i 

LEFT JOIN 
inv_order i_o on i_o.invID=i.invID

LEFT JOIN 
`item-service` item on item.itemID = i_o.itemID


LEFT JOIN person p on 
p.PID=i.personID

where i.shiftID =97
```

but then, i need to get the employee name from the employee table, and i only have the shiftID.

```
SELECT
i.dateTime,i.type,i.amount,i.totalProfit,i.shiftID,i_o.itemID,i_o.quantity,item.name itemName,p.full_name

from invoice i 

LEFT JOIN 
inv_order i_o on i_o.invID=i.invID

LEFT JOIN 
`item-service` item on item.itemID = i_o.itemID


LEFT JOIN person p on 
p.PID=i.personID

where i.shiftID =97

UNION

SELECT e.name from employee e

left join shift s on s.empID = e.empID

where s.shiftID =97
```

the mysql return this error

**The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The used SELECT statements have a different number of columns (REDUX!!)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3655708/the-used-select-statements-have-a-different-number-of-columns-redux)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message is quite clear as to the problem: your first query returns 8 columns of data and your second only 1, so you can't `UNION` them. It seems you probably want to just `JOIN` the `employee` table via the `shift` table e.g.

```
SELECT i.dateTime
      ,i.type
      ,i.amount
      ,i.totalProfit
      ,i.shiftID
      ,i_o.itemID
      ,i_o.quantity
      ,item.name AS itemName
      ,p.full_name
      ,e.name
FROM invoice i 
LEFT JOIN inv_order i_o ON i_o.invID=i.invID
LEFT JOIN `item-service` item ON item.itemID = i_o.itemID
LEFT JOIN person p ON p.PID=i.personID
LEFT JOIN shift s ON s.shiftID = i.shiftID
LEFT JOIN employee e ON e.empID = s.empID
WHERE i.shiftID = 97
```